# Trouble with Java inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an abstract java class that looks like:

```
public abstract class X  {
    public abstract void commonFunction();
}
```

I also have a bunch of maps, that I would like to be like this:

```
Map<String,A> mapA = new HashMap<String,A>();
Map<String,B> mapB = new HashMap<String,B>();
Map<String,C> mapC = new HashMap<String,C>();
Map<String,D> mapD = new HashMap<String,D>();
Map<String,E> mapE = new HashMap<String,E>();
```

A, B, C, D and E all extend X so they all implement `commonFunction()`.
I'd like to be able to call a function like this:

```
someFunction(mapA); // or someFunction(mapB) etc.
```

...where someFunction looks like:

```
void someFunction(Map<String,X> mapX) {
    ...some stuff
    x.commonFunction();
    ...more stuff
}
```

But the compiler complains with the things I've tried, which includes:

- changing the map declarations (left-hand side) by replacing [ABCDE] with X
- casting the map into `Map<String,X>` inside the `someFunction` function call

Also tried with an implemented interface instead of an extended class. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit:**
I'm sorry, I rushed the question so I made a mistake. My maps are actually:

```
Map<String,List<A>> mapA = new HashMap<String,List<A>>();
```

...and so the `someFunction` signature is actually:

```
void someFunction(Map<String,List<X>> mapX)
```

I'm not sure if that makes a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring

```
<T extends X> void someFunction(Map<String,List<T>> mapX)
```

Even `A` being a subclass of `X`, `Map<String,List<A>>` is **not** a subclass of `Map<String,List<X>>`.

You need to use a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) as above to have a parameter that accepts any `Map<String, List<any class that extends X>>` ("any class that extends `X`" is represented by the type parameter `T`).

Comment: Yep, this did the trick. There's other correct answers around but the explanation is good and you got there first!

Comment: Is there any serious issues if I wanted to change X to be an interface instead of a class? The compiler doesn't seem to mind if I leave everything as it is except change the definition of X to an interface, but if I change your code above to `<T implements X>` the compiler doesn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

> But the compiler complains with the things I've tried

The rules of polymorphism does not apply to generics.

```
List<X> list = new ArrayList<A>; // Invalid. Polymorphism does not in declaration or referencing
```

However, this is valid:

```
List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>;
list.add(new A()); // Can add sub-type of X
list.add(new B());
```

Try this:

```
void someFunction(Map<String,? extends X> mapX) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `X` in your method, you must access it through the Map, like so

```
mapX.get("myKey").commonFunction();
```

Just tested it with this:

```
void tester() {
    Map<String, X> testMap = new HashMap<String,X >();
    testMap.put("myKey", new A());
    someFunction(testMap);
}

void someFunction(Map<String, X> myMap) {
    myMap.get("myKey").doSomething();
}

abstract class X {
    abstract void doSomething();
}

class A extends X {
    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm A");
    } 
}

class B extends X {
    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm B");
    } 
}

class C extends X {
    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm C");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<K extends X> void someFunction( Map<String, List<K>> mapX ) {
    for ( List<K> list : mapX.values() ) {
        for ( X obj : list ) {
            obj.commonFunction();
        }
    }
}
```